# Upload file to ftp with node.js and npm ftp (ftp from GoDaddy)

Tags: node.js, express, ftp

I'm triying to upload files to my FTP which lives on GoDaddy Hosting Plan Deluxe with Express.js. After a lot of search found the [NPM ftp library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ftp)

I've followed the instructions to connect to my ftp account (a special account to upload files) but now i can't upload the file. Next, my code so far:

```
const express = require('express');
var Client = require('ftp');

const app = express();

c.connect({
    host: thehost,
    port: 21,
    user: theuser,
    password: thepass,
});

var c = new Client();
c.on('ready', function() {
  c.list(function(err, list) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.dir(list);
    c.end();
  });
});

app.post('/files', async (req, res) => {

          let myFile = req.files.filesBox;

          let cleanName = myFile.name.replace(/[`~!@#$%^&*()|+\=?;:'"áéíóúâêîûãõçÇñÑ, <>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '-');

var c = new Client();
          c.on('ready', function() {
            c.put(cleanName, function(err) {
              if (err) throw err;
              c.end();
            });
          }); 

          c.connect();
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(port, () => 
  console.log(`App on port: ${port}`)
);
```

As you can see, i get the file name using `let myFile = req.files.filesBox;` (filesBox is the name of the form), then i remove all the special characters with `let cleanName` and then, send the file. My problem is that the response messages is:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:21
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
```

Someone knows why is not working? I´ve readed on a forum that the response comes 'cause i'm not connecting properly to the FTP. But when the conection begins, there's no error response, and the dir list is printed on the console like this:

```
[ { name: 'images',
    type: 'd',
    size: 0,
    date: 2019-10-13T20:28:00.000Z },
  { name: 'remote-folder',
    type: 'd',
    size: 0,
    date: 2019-10-06T05:13:00.000Z } ]
```

I'm missing something? Someone had the same error?

I made a test with FileZilla and the testing images uploaded without problems.

Hope you can help me.

As i said, i'm working with Node, Express and NPM FTP library